# How to edit include path in g++ when using 'R CMD Install --library=**my path** myfile.tar.gz'?

Tags: c++, r, ubuntu-16.04, rcpp

I have an R package built in Rstudio, which contains a lot of c++ files. After successfully building the R package, I try to install it using the command `R CMD INSTALL --library=**my path** myfile.tar.gz` in the terminal.

Since I have a lot of c++ code in my R package, g++ tries to compile this code but could not find certain header files.

Is there a way to point the g++ compiler to the location of my header files, I tried using `PKG_CXXFLAGS` but in vain.

[image]

Comment: Please do not post images of error message but insert them as formatted text. What did you put in `PKG_CXXFLAGS`? Normally `PKG_CPPFLAGS` is the right place to include header locations.

Comment: In addition: How/Where did you define `PKG_CXXFLAGS`?

Comment: @RalfStubner I set my header files location in     PKG_CPPFLAGS     , and ran the setup but it failed throwing the same error. Defined it in the terminal using export command.

Comment: And how/where did you define `PKG_CPPFLAGS`?

Comment: It really sounds like you have, contrary to your claim, _not_ correctly set up your package.  Your `src/Makevars` is where you set `-I....` as needed.

Comment: It would be much easier to definitively say precisely what you've done wrong if you could link to your package code, e.g., in a GitHub repository.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! I found a work around. Just included all the header files as required to the path from where g++ was reading from. Though tedious it solved my problem.